# Why/how would a domain URL show client's localhost address?

Tags: security, http, url, dns

I was trying to go to http://lustiges-taschenbuch.de which is a valid comic book site.

I mistyped the address as http://lustigestaschenbuch.de and was surprised to see my own apache localhost directory (!). This happens on two computers in Windows 7.

I checked my c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file but it has nothing listed.

I looked it up on http://www.whoishostingthis.com on this site but it cannot find an owner.

I looked it up on denic, and it says the owner is:

```
Domaininhaber:      Tapon del Darien LLC
Organisation:   Tapon del Darien LLC
Adresse:    First Floor-Commercial Area
Calle 53 , Marbella
P.O. BOX 0832-0588
PLZ:    0832-0588
Ort:    Panama City
Land:   PA
```

**Can anyone explain why and how this domain is showing the client computer's localhost directory?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry!  The DNS settings for the domain just point it back to the localhost address `127.0.0.1` for anyone that visits the address they'll see their local server (or a 404 message if they don't have one), but it doesn't mean anyone else can see it/will see it when they visit the domain.  I don't know why it's set that way for the domain, perhaps the domain owner can tell you.

**dig output:**

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lustigestaschenbuch.de. 86400   IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
lustigestaschenbuch.de. 86400   IN      NS      ns2.sedoparking.com.
lustigestaschenbuch.de. 86400   IN      NS      ns1.sedoparking.com.
```

... the `sedoparking.com` suggests perhaps someone bought & parked this domain for use later, or is sitting on it hoping to sell it later.

Comment: but is there a (hacking) reason for doing this, e.g perhaps certain localhosts are set up to send information to the original URL which directed to it, etc? I'm just trying to think of a reason why someone would go through the trouble to redirect a URL they are sitting on to a client's localhost

Comment: It's not a client's localhost, it is the localhost of the visiting machine.  There's no hacking benefit (the DNS server can't do anything about it, it just provides the IP for the requested domain, it's up to whatever's requesting the info to decide what to do with it).  It could be because the domain owner has no other use for it, and likes to visit his own machine in the browser by typing in `http://lustigestaschenbuch.de`

Comment: An approximate simile: Abe registers his phone number as 0 in the phonebook.  When you call Abe, he doesn't automatically learn everything from the operator - in fact he doesn't even know you made the call (meanwhile the operator doesn't know why everyone's asking for Abe ;)).

Comment: yes, that's what I meant: client = visiting machine, that makes sense I suppose, in any case, it's disconcerting to anyone who visits it and has a site set up on localhost :-o